# Regular expression to string or int conversion

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I want to convert the matched expression in string or int. But in .NET Framework I do not find any method to do this. I've tried this

```
s=+OK 58 exists;
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"\+OK (?<totalemail>[0-9]+)");
        Console.WriteLine("Total Email: " + m.Groups["totalemail"].Value);
        string s1= Convert.ToString(m.Groups["totalemail"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine(s1);
```

This first writeline prints 58 and the second `WriteLine()` call prints nothing that means `s1=""`.

If I use `int` conversion like this

```
int s=Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups["totalemail"].Value);
```

then it shows error

> Input String is not in correct format.

Is it possible to convert matched regular expression to `string` or `int`? if possible please give help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo. This:

```
"totalemail]"
```

should be this:

```
"totalemail"
```

Comment: thanks.it is writing mistake. However this is not the problem.
and my problem is solved.

Comment: @MdKamruzzamanPallob You say "my problem is solved". Please post the solution as an answer. It might help other people in future.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/241605/matthew-strawbridge thanks. i have posted my solution

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it. Solution will be like this--

```
  s=+OK 58 exists;

  var m = Regex.Match(s, @"\+OK (?<totalemail>[0-9]+)");
        Console.WriteLine("Total Email: " + m.Groups["totalemail"].Value);
        int index = m.Groups["totalemail"].Index;
        int length = m.Groups["totalemail"].Length;
        Console.WriteLine(index + "  " + length);
        string str;
       Console.WriteLine(str=m.ToString().Substring(index,length));
        int i;
       Console.WriteLine(i = Convert.ToInt32(str));
```